# Next.js + Sanity.io debugging: "async/await is not yet supported in Client Components, only Server Components."

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, async-await, sanity

Beginner here building a website/e-commerce store using React, Next 14, Typescript, and Sanity for the CMS. I was following this tutorial here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g2sE034SGjw&t

I'm receiving the following error:

> *unhandled runtime error*
>
> *async/await is not yet supported in Client Components, only Server Components.*

I have a parent component `<ProductGridApp />` that is returning the child component `<ProductGrid />` in a div, which is then rendered in Home() in `page.tsx`

I'm not using the `"use client"` directive in either component, except for in `page.tsx` , where the parent component `<ProductGridApp />` is called.

Here is the code for `<ProductGridApp />`:

```
import React from "react";
import { ProductGrid } from "./product-grid";
import { SanityProduct } from "../../imgsandbox/config/inventory";
import { siteConfig } from "../../imgsandbox/config/site";
import { client } from "../../imgsandbox/sanity/lib/client";
import { groq } from "next-sanity";
import "../components/local-css/card.css";

interface Props {
  products: SanityProduct[];
}

export default async function ProductGridApp() {
  const products = await client.fetch<SanityProduct[]>(
    groq`*[_type == "product"] 
    {
      _id,
      _createdAt,
      name,
      sku,
      images,
      currency,
      price,
      description,
      "slug": slug.current
  }`
  );
  console.log(products);

  return (
    <div className="card card-text card-text-x">
      <h1>{siteConfig.name}</h1>
      <h3>{siteConfig.description}</h3>
      <div>
        <ProductGrid products={products} />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
console.log("Shop Loaded");
```

Here is the code for `<ProductGrid />`:

```
import Image from "next/image";
import Link from "next/link";
import { urlForImage } from "../../imgsandbox/sanity/lib/image";
import { XCircle } from "lucide-react";
import { formatCurrencyString } from "use-shopping-cart";
import { SanityProduct } from "../../imgsandbox/config/inventory";

interface Props {
  products: SanityProduct[];
}

export function ProductGrid({ products }: Props) {
  if (!products || products.length === 0) {
    return (
      <div className="mx-auto grid h-40 w-full place-items-center rounded-md border-2 border-dashed bg-gray-50 py-10 text-center dark:bg-gray-900">
        <div>
          <XCircle className="mx-auto h-10 w-10 text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-200" />
          <h1 className="mt-2 text-xl font-bold tracking-tight text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-200 sm:text-2xl">
            No products found
          </h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }

  return (
    <div className="grid grid-cols-1 gap-x-6 gap-y-10 sm:grid-cols-3 lg:col-span-3 lg:gap-x-8">
      {!products ||
        products.map((product) => (
          <Link
            key={product._id}
            href={`/products/${product.slug}`}
            className="group text-sm"
          >
            <div className="aspect-h-1 aspect-w-1 w-full overflow-hidden rounded-lg border-2 border-gray-200 bg-gray-100 group-hover:opacity-75 dark:border-gray-800">
              <Image
                src={urlForImage(product.images[0])}
                alt={product.name}
                width={225}
                height={280}
                className="h-full w-full object-cover object-center"
              />
            </div>
            <h3 className="mt-4 font-medium">Name</h3>
            <p className="mt-2 font-medium">Price</p>
          </Link>
        ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

What's worse, is that I'm not receiving errors in my Chrome Dev Tools console or in my VSCode terminal and am just receiving a blank white screen, so I'm really at a loss when trying to troubleshoot this. I've been looking at this problem for a few days now and can't do it on my own.

Can anyone help?

- Removing "use client" directive
- Ensure correct import of components
- Ensure the async/await function is happening on the server-side when trying to fetch the data(?)

Comment: I'm not well versed in this framework, but I assume the `"use client"` pragma is transitive. If it weren't I don't see how it could restrict these things meaningfully.

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch the data on server side by using `getServerSideProps`, thats what its for to construct the page and render page to user. But you can do this in the page component only.

This is how it will work

```
import React from "react";
import { ProductGrid } from "./product-grid";
import { SanityProduct } from "../../imgsandbox/config/inventory";
import { siteConfig } from "../../imgsandbox/config/site";
import { client } from "../../imgsandbox/sanity/lib/client";
import { groq } from "next-sanity";
import "../components/local-css/card.css";

interface Props {
  products: SanityProduct[];
}

export default function ProductGridApp(props) {
  console.info('props', props);

  return (
    <div className="card card-text card-text-x">
      <h1>{siteConfig.name}</h1>
      <h3>{siteConfig.description}</h3>
      <div>
        <ProductGrid products={props?.products || []} />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}


export const getServerSideProps = () => {
  try {
    const products = await client.fetch<SanityProduct[]>(
      groq`*[_type == "product"] 
      {
        _id,
        _createdAt,
        name,
        sku,
        images,
        currency,
        price,
        description,
        "slug": slug.current
    }`
    );
    return {
      props: {
        products
      }
    }
  } catch (error) {
    return {
      props: {
        // use this to show error to user or perform other action based on this
        error: 'an error occured'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Read more on `getServerSideProps` [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/data-fetching/get-server-side-props)